# Set mileage destination displaying

Tags: excel

I have some experience with excel but its very limited. I have a list of regular To & From destinations setup as historical data along with the mileage between.

What I have is basically cell A1 WIGAN + cell B1 LUTTERWORTH in Sheet 2 and I want a formula to match both of these from Sheet 1 and display the mileage. If the journey has no history then to display a NIL value.

It sounds simple but as yet I've not located anything that works or been able to work it out myself.

[image]

Comment: What are you having trouble with?  Writing the formula, or creating the correct cell references?

Comment: could you show a mock up of how the data is exactly?

Comment: its a formula Im looking for thanks, I think its a combo of IF and VLOOKUP but struggling to get it to work.

Comment: i have 3 columns, From - To - Miles, so i want a formula to basically look at WREXHAM in A2 and match it with GATESHEAD in B2 then look up the match on a separate sheet of historical data and display the miles if there is a match in C2. i hope that makes sense, its essentially a shortcut to me having to fill in the mileage all the time against destinations that are regularly done

Comment: It is impossible to tell if you are describing a matrix or two column lookup. Should I just guess?

Comment: i.m pretty sure its a lookup

Comment: ... and yet you still feel it is unnecessary to provide any sample data.

Comment: theres not much to show tbh, i have a list of TO and FROM destinations with the Mileage against them on Sheet 1, on Sheet 2 I have similar info without any mileage. If i knew how to attach or upload a sheet i would

Comment: Then it should be easy to grab a picture of the data, post it on imugr and post a link in your original post.  Or in your original post show a matrix of the what the data would look like.  It is hard to give you a formula without any reference.

Comment: http://imgur.com/6f8L3Va : http://imgur.com/X9o9ceQ. so i need a formula to match eg. WIGAN with NEWHOUSE, look for these matching in sheet 1 data and bring me back the mileage on sheet 2.

Comment: I took a stab in the dark.  The photo you provided did not state whether this is the output or input.  A good example of the desired photos is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34594191/is-it-possible-to-output-the-values-of-a-column-in-excel-based-on-a-dynamic-date/34594357#34594357).  There is one photo of the data and one of the desired output.  Otherwise you get our assumption of what you want.

Comment: @Bigste you should mark jeepeds answer below as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=INDEX('Sheet1'!C:C,MATCH("NEWHOUSE",IF('Sheet1'!A:A = "WIGAN",'Sheet1'!B:B),0))
```

It is an array formula and must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Change the Column references to the actual reference; change C:C to $C$2:$C$1000.  It will speed it up.

Comment: Thanks, its working for the example (newbridge-wigan) is it possible for the formula to look at the cells rather than a typed name? something that is easily dragged down to the other cells below? when i switch the name to a cell ref it #N/A's

Comment: @Bigste When you switched it did you hit Ctrl-Shift Enter when done? Becuase `=INDEX('Sheet1'!C:C,MATCH(B2,IF('Sheet1'!A:A = A2,'Sheet1'!B:B),0))`.  Should work if you exited edit mode with ctrl-shift-enter.  But you should look into what Jeeped's answer it more dynamic.

Comment: Yes I did Ctrl Shft and Enter. Thanks i'll try Jeeped's

Answer (score 1):

You could minimize the cross-reference table of mileage values by adding a reversed lookup if the first fails.

[image: aggregate_mileage]

In Sheet5!C2 as,

```
=INDEX(Mileage!C:C, IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($1:$99)/((Mileage!$A$1:$A$99=A2)*(Mileage!$B$1:$B$99=B2)), 1), AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($1:$99)/((Mileage!$A$1:$A$99=B2)*(Mileage!$B$1:$B$99=A2)), 1)))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, I'm getting an error in the formula, I've checked it over a few times and cant see anything I've mistyped. =INDEX(Mileage!C:C, IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15, 6 ROW($1:$99)/((Mileage!$A$1:$A$99=A2)*(Mileage!$B$1:$B$99=B2)), 1), AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($1:$99)/((Mileage!$A$1:$A$99=B2)*(Mileage!$B$1:$B$99=A2)), 1)))

Comment: You're missing a comma in the first aggregate's `6 ROW($1:$99)`. Should be `6, ROW($1:$99)`. Of courses, that assumes that your system uses a comma as a list delimiter; some European (and other) countries use a semi-colon.

Comment: You are a Genius!! you have no idea how much this helps, its saved probably 4-5 days work with this. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad you got sorted out.